# Getting last image dates automatically in Google Earth

Tags: google-earth

I want to check whether Google Earth has an up-to-date image (taken in this year) for a given location. I can do it manually by checking the location on Google Earth Pro. However, since I am interested in many location at the same time, I am looking for a table that shows cities, for example, and their corresponding last image date. With this information, I want simply sort cities that has an image in 2020, for example, and analyze these cities.

Is there any way of getting it?